# Why can lorentz transformation be expressed like this

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, quantum-mechanics

Why can the lorentz transformation: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/3/e/e3ee37f49f0adb02bc81590cb697d4d0.png

Also be expressed as https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/d/6/0d6f3185dd8047b094a17478eed58b22.png

?

I understand that ct is time and space understood as length (example meters) but how do I read that from this transformation change?

Comment: Just compute the matrix multiplication, and observe that you get the same result.

Comment: But why can we just call t = ct? Time isn't the same thing as timespace.

Answer (score 0):

From the original Lorentz transformation

$$ \left[ \begin{array} 
\ t' \\
 x' \\
 y' \\
 z' \\
 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array} 
\ \gamma & -\frac{v}{c^{2}}\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
 -v\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array} 
\ t \\
 x \\
 y \\
 z \\
 \end{array} \right] $$

we have the following system of equations:

$$ \mathrm{(1)} \qquad \gamma \cdot t - \frac{v}{c^{2}}\gamma \cdot x = t' $$
$$ \mathrm{(2)} \qquad -v\gamma \cdot t + \gamma \cdot x = x'$$
$$ \mathrm{(3)} \qquad y = y'$$
$$ \mathrm{(4)} \qquad z = z'$$

From the revised Lorentz transformation
$$ \left[ \begin{array} 
\ ct' \\
 x' \\
 y' \\
 z' \\
 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array} 
\ \gamma & -\frac{v}{c}\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{v}{c}\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array} 
\ ct \\
 x \\
 y \\
 z \\
 \end{array} \right] $$

we have the following system of equations:

$$ \mathrm{(5)} \qquad \gamma \cdot ct - \frac{v}{c}\gamma \cdot x = ct' $$
$$ \mathrm{(6)} \qquad -\frac{v}{c}\gamma \cdot ct + \gamma \cdot x = x'$$
$$ \mathrm{(7)} \qquad y = y'$$
$$ \mathrm{(8)} \qquad z = z'$$

Multiply a $ c $ to each side of equation $ (1) $ to obtain equation $ (5) $:
$$ \gamma \cdot t - \frac{v}{c^{2}}\gamma \cdot x = t' $$ or
$$ c (\gamma \cdot t - \frac{v}{c^{2}}\gamma \cdot x) = c (t') $$ or
$$ c \gamma \cdot t - c \frac{v}{c^{2}}\gamma \cdot x = ct' $$ or 
$$ \gamma \cdot ct - \frac{v}{c}\gamma \cdot x = ct'$$

Equation $ (6) $ becomes equation $ (2) $ because $$ -\frac{v}{c}\gamma \cdot ct = -v \gamma \cdot t $$

Equations $ (3) $ and $ (4) $ are identical to equations $ (7) $ and $ (8) $ respectively.